# How should I model this relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I'm relatively new to PHP and just started to learn Laravel. I leave a few questions regarding a personal learning project I'm working on. Thank you in advance for any feedback!

***CONTEXT:***

My project is using the default laravel 7.x UI and auth scaffolding. I'v implemented user roles with a *roles* table and a *role_user* table. This works as intended (e.g. I can perform CRUD on users and their roles)

```
Many users can have many roles.

ROLES:
Customer
Agent
Admin
```

I run into trouble when trying to implement user **Statuses**. Like this:

**Users** with the **Role** of **Agent** can have only *one* **Status** at any given time; either 'AVAILABLE' or 'BUSY'.

***QUESTIONS:***

#1. **How should I define the Agent User/Status relationship?** Initially I did Many to Many. I created a statuses table and status_user table. Later I concluded that this was incorrect and changed the relationship to Many to One as seen below. ( I didn't change any of my tables)

In the **Users** Model:

```
    public function statuses(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Status');

    }
```

In the **Status** Model:

```
    public function users(){

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');

    }
```

***Some thoughts:***

After having trouble with some queries I'm starting to think using the two tables (statuses and status_user) is in incorrect given how I modeled them above.

Should I rollback and just add a "status_id" column to the user table while keeping the tables as is? I'm starting to think I'm getting the entire relationship wrong.

Maybe I shouldn't be relating status to the users table; instead to a separate 'Agents' table?

Comment: If any user can have at the most only one status then adding `status_id` column would be the way to go. `status_id` needs to be a nullable column if there's any possibility that when creating a User record status may be unknown.

Comment: Maybe you're overengineering this. How about a single status column on the user saying `Available, Busy, N/A` (n/a for non-agents)?